# Eclipse will not use gcc 4.7 on Mac

Tags: gcc

I installed gcc47 using macports.  I used select to make gcc47 my active compiler.  When I type gcc --version in terminal I get this:
 gcc (MacPorts gcc47 4.7.2_2) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

When I try to compile c++ code in Eclipse I get:
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ -I/Users/XXXX/QtSDK/Madde/sysroots/harmattan_sysroot_10.2011.34-1_slim/usr -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -MMD -MP -MF"XXXX_Process.d" -MT"XXXX_Process.d" -o "XXXX_Process.o" "../XXXX_Process.cpp"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"
make: *** [XXXX_Process.o] Error 1

I am not sure what I am not doing to make this work.  I need a more up to date compiler for programs I am writing in my for school.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: -std=c++11 does not work either

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the order of discovery on the path for eclipse is different then the order in your terminal. I had tried symlinking as suggest above and that still didn't fix my problem, but this did!

After much searching around and trying other things, I was able to manually set the path to my compilers and linkers in `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings`.

from the terminal, do a which g++ to find out where your proper version of g++ is installed.  Mine is in `/opt/local/bin/g++`

Click on GCC C++ Compiler, and fill in the command with it's full path (eg. `/opt/local/bin/g++`).  Click on Miscellaneous to make sure you add the `-std=c++11` flag.

Do the same thing for GCC C Compiler (set the command to the full path `/opt/local/bin/g++`), The GCC C++ Linker (`/opt/local/bin/g++`), and the GCC Assembler (`/opt/local/bin/as`).

This FINALLY worked for me, I hope it solves your problem!

Answer (score 2):

MacPorts installs gcc to `/opt/local/bin`, leaving `/usr/bin` untouched. The former is apparently higher precedence in the default shell `$PATH`, so the shell will find the gcc under `/opt/local/bin`, even though `/usr/bin/gcc` still points to the mac LLVM-gcc-4.2 compiler. Eclipse apparently does not set up `$PATH` the same way as the terminal, and so finds the `/usr/bin/` version.

I was able to fix this by manually symlinking `/usr/bin/{gcc,g++}` to the MacPorts versions.

Answer (score -2):

When you entered the  -stdc++11, did you put a "space" between the -c -fmessage-length=0 and it? Like...-c -fmessage-length=0 -stdc++11   not -c -fmessage-length=0-stdc++11. That single space was preventing eclipse from recognizing gcc in windows.