# Eclipse CDT is not using the correct version of gcc

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, eclipse-cdt

On an OS X machine (Snow Leopard, if it matters), I'm attempting to upgrade from gcc 4.2.1 to 4.7.3.

I followed instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153725/installing-gcc-4-7-1-on-os-x) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361002/how-to-use-the-gcc-installed-in-macports), and can now compile code using either -std=c++0x or std=c++11 from the command line.

But Eclipse CDT still appears to be using the old gcc version.  I edited my project so that it has std=c++0x as a miscellaneous argument to the compiler.  And yet, when I do a build within CDT I get the following output:

```
07:48:16 **** Build of configuration Debug for project 4.1 Valuation ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/BondModel.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"
make: *** [src/BondModel.o] Error 1
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -MMD -MP -MF"src/BondModel.d" -MT"src/BondModel.d" -o "src/BondModel.o" "../src/BondModel.cpp"

07:48:16 Build Finished (took 109ms)
```

if I copy and paste that g++ line to terminal, it runs fine.

What do I need to change in eclipse so that it uses the installed and selected version of gcc?

Comment: OK, sorry, I missed that... In that case, I have no idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The answer has to do with where MacPorts puts gcc, as opposed to where XCode puts it.

- MacPorts: /opt/local/bin/gcc
- XCode: /usr/bin

So even after you install a later version of gcc with MacPorts, eclipse still uses the old one.

After finding this in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870257/eclipse-will-not-use-gcc-4-7-on-mac), I fixed this by changing the compiler and linker in `Project Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings`, MacOS X C++ Linker and GCC C++ Compiler to have as their command `/opt/bin/local/g++` instead of `g++`.

This did not completely resolve my issues, because the CDT UI is still complaining about C++ 11 features, but I can build my project and run it.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem with CDT UI (e.g., syntax highlighting and code completion)?

Comment: I have managed to fix the issue with CDT UI :) You can see what I did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086835/using-clang-for-code-analysis-in-an-autotools-project-in-eclipse).